# Javascript How exactly does this program re loop the code to 'move the circles', learning javascript and canvas for a class

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm in a web multimedia class and we are learning how to use html5's canvas and javascript to create interactivity in web pages.  we are going over example programs from the book and I have been running through the code in my head in order to grasp it clearly.  I'm having trouble with this current example:
what I understand:

it uses a `'glasspane'` div to set a small menu above the actual canvas because apparently you have to use html controls outside of the canvas element, because it cannot run both the `canvas .js` and the html controls.

in the `.js` file:

- it starts by getting the elements by their id's and then creates an array of circles of random size and color.
- it adds a mouse click event to the id startButton that stops the animation through stopPropogation, then swaps the bool value of paused.
- Paused is used in the setInterval function and decides whether the code to clear and redraw screen and then draw the circles and then run a function to change the circle position by 1 and reverse the velocity so they 'bounce' off of the canvas borders.

What I don't understand:

- is the setInterval function a special function that knows to continue looping through the code? If that's not how the code loops with new x and y values to show the circles 'move' what part does that?
- How does the animation restart after stopPropogation is used?
- what exactly do the glasspane.onmousedown and context.canvas.onmousedown functions do? The only thing that changes the program on the user side is clicking on the start/stop text which must run through `startButton.onclick`.

Code is below.

```
javascript:

var context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'),
    startButton = document.getElementById('startButton'),
    glasspane = document.getElementById('glasspane'),
    paused = true,
    circles = [];

drawGrid(context, 'lightgray', 10, 10);

context.lineWidth = 0.5;
context.font = '32pt Arial';

for (var i=0; i < 100; ++i) {
   circles[i] = { 
       x: 100, 
       y: 100, 
       velocityX: 3*Math.random(), 
       velocityY: 3*Math.random(), 
       radius: 50*Math.random(),
       color: 'rgba(' + (Math.random()*255).toFixed(0) + ', ' +
                        (Math.random()*255).toFixed(0) + ', ' +
                        (Math.random()*255).toFixed(0) + ', 1.0)' };
}

startButton.onclick = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   paused = ! paused;
   startButton.innerText = paused ? 'Start' : 'Stop';
};

glasspane.onmousedown = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
}

context.canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
};

setInterval(function() {
   if (!paused) {
      context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
      drawGrid(context, 'lightgray', 10, 10);

      circles.forEach(function(circle) {
         context.beginPath();
         context.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circle.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
         context.fillStyle = circle.color;
         context.fill(); 
         adjustPosition(circle);
      });
   }
}, 1000 / 60);

function adjustPosition(circle) {
   if (circle.x + circle.velocityX + circle.radius > context.canvas.width ||
       circle.x + circle.velocityX - circle.radius < 0) 
      circle.velocityX = -circle.velocityX;

   if (circle.y + circle.velocityY + circle.radius > context.canvas.height ||
       circle.y + circle.velocityY - circle.radius  < 0) 
      circle.velocityY= -circle.velocityY;

   circle.x += circle.velocityX;
   circle.y += circle.velocityY;
}

function drawGrid(context, color, stepx, stepy) {
   context.strokeStyle = color;
   context.lineWidth = 0.5;

   for (var i = stepx + 0.5; i < context.canvas.width; i += stepx) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(i, 0);
      context.lineTo(i, context.canvas.height);
      context.stroke();
   }

   for (var i = stepy + 0.5; i < context.canvas.height; i += stepy) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(0, i);
      context.lineTo(context.canvas.width, i);
      context.stroke();
   }
}
```

**html:**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Bouncing Balls</title>

      <style> 
         body {
            background: #dddddd;
         }

         #canvas {
            margin-left: 10px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            background: #ffffff;
            border: thin solid #aaaaaa;
         }

         #glasspane {
            position: absolute;
            left: 50px;
            top: 50px;
            padding: 0px 20px 10px 10px;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            border: thin solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
            color: #eeeeee;
            font-family: Droid Sans, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            cursor: pointer;
            -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 5px 5px 20px;
            -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 5px 5px 20px;
            box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 5px 5px 20px;
         }

         #glasspane h2 {
            font-weight: normal;
         }

         #glasspane .title {
            font-size: 2em;
            color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.8);
         }

         #glasspane a:hover {
            color: yellow;
         }

         #glasspane a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #cccccc;
            font-size: 3.5em;
         }

         #glasspane p {
            margin: 10px;
            color: rgba(65, 65, 220, 1.0);
            font-size: 12pt;
            font-family: Palatino, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
         }
      </style>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id='glasspane'>
         <h2 class='title'>Bouncing Balls</h2>

         <p>One hundred balls bouncing</p>

         <a id='startButton'>Start</a>
      </div>

      <canvas id='canvas' width='750' height='500'>
         Canvas not supported
      </canvas>

      <script src='example.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of exploring such code is experimenting with it. Try commenting parts of it out and see what happens.

Anyways, about your questions - I'm not sure why the `onmousedown` handlers are there. They don't seem to do anything useful here. But maybe there is a point.

On the `setInterval` function - it's not special. It just repeatedly executes the function which was passed to it. It tries to execute it once every `1000/60` milliseconds, which works out to 60 times a second.

(Mind you, in production code nobody uses `setInterval`. Instead `requestAnimationFrame` is the correct way to go; or if that's not available - at least `setTimeout`. But that's a separate discussion and maybe you'll still get to that part in your class. Using `setInterval` in an example would however make sense because it's simpler than the alternatives)

Note also that the function that was passed to `setInterval` in this example has all it's contents wrapped in `if (!paused) { ... }` - that's what's taking care of the pauses. When the animation is paused, the function still gets called, but it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Wonderful answers, thank you.  My last question would be: is the swapping of paused that is the only thing that determines if the setInterval code gets run?  If so what does stopPropogation do in this instance?  I see it gets ran on every mouse click just like the swapping of the value of paused is ran on every click

Comment: @JGoss - `stopPropagation` has to do with "event bubbling". In HTML, when you click on some element, the `click` event will be called both on the child element, and all its parents too, all the way up to the topmost `<html>` element. That is, unless one of the elements in the chain has an event handler which calls `stopPropagation()`. Then further parents don't get the event. There's also a "capturing" phase before the "bubbling" phase, which is the same thing in reverse - all the parent elements get the notification first (but they need to register their event handlers in a special way).

Comment: @JGoss - the `preventDefault()` on the other hand has to do with the default actions the browser would take. For instance, clicking a link makes the browser follow that link - unless there's a `click` event handler that calls `preventDefault()`. There are other default actions that can be prevented this way too, however browser compatibility starts to get a bit shaky at places (that is, there are some actions that are preventable in one browser but not in another).

Comment: @JGoss - `is the swapping of paused that is the only thing that determines if the setInterval code gets run?` - I'll try to be extremely precise here so as to clear the confusion. The "`setInterval()` code" - that is, the function which was passed to `setInterval()` - gets run 60 times per second no matter what. No clicking of buttons affects it. However **inside** that function there is an `if (!paused)` statement, which executes _the drawing code_ only when the variable `paused` is `false`. And that variable changes its value when you click the button.